# Simple Kafka Consumer Example not working through java api

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am writing the java api to create kafka consumer I have an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.Consumer.subscribe(Ljava/util/Collection;)V
at in.co.hadooptutorials.data.generator.cdr.kafkaconsumer.main(kafkaconsumer.java:38)
```

below is my code:

```java
public class kafkaconsumer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String TOPIC_NAME = "test";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,"localhost:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test" );
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", "30000");
    props.put("partition.assignment.strategy", "range");
    Consumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>.(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("test"));
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);

    System.out.println(consumer);
    System.out.println(records);
    consumer.close();
  } 
}

pem file:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>in.co.hadooptutorials</groupId>
  <artifactId>cdr-data-generator</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>cdr-data-generator</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.Final</version>

      </extension>
    </extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        <logback.contrib.version>0.1.5</logback.contrib.version>
        <docx4j.version>3.3.5</docx4j.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.cassandraunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-unit</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
            <version>${docx4j.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am Adding the adding the code of my pem file full code of pem file
also adding the jar of kafka clients-2.2.0
Its a project of cdr data to store the data into cassandra using kafka
How to solve this problem?
I am trying still getting the error.

Comment: i bet you are using a kafka version below 0.10. Update it and the problem is gone

Comment: can you please send the link to download the kafka

Comment: I am using kafka_2.12-2.2.0 this version

Comment: Can you show us your dependencies in pom file?

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: maven-compiler-plugin needs to be Java 1.8 if you want to use Kafka 2.x

Comment: Also, it would be recommended not to write your own consumer for a database https://docs.lenses.io/connectors/sink/cassandra.html

Comment: Yes i use java 1.8

Comment: Now error is :Failed to construct kafka consumer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that in you POM file you have the following dependencies:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: @ShrJoshi Added one more dependency. See my updated answer and let me know how it goes